# Eclipse - debugger doesn't stop at xTend code breakpoints, but possible to java code breakpoints

Tags: java, xtend

I am developer who is using xTend. The docs for this kind of programming language are introduced at this link:

https://www.eclipse.org/xtend/documentation/

[image]

When I used Eclipse Photon version to develop my product. I ran into the issue related to debugging.
AFAIK, xTend code will always be intermediately compiled to java code first.

The issue description as below:

- The debugger can hit breakpoints if they are toggled in java code.
- But, when I toggle breakpoints in xTend code, the debugger doesn't hit the breakpoints any longer.

I tried some times to refresh my Eclipse workspace (delete old one / create new one), even used other version of Eclipse. But, still didn't solve the issue.

Who had already run into this situation, could you share your idea or solution on this ?

Comment: It looked like the bug of Eclipse IDE. I was searching at some forums, but there's no solution.

Comment: https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do?bug_id=6862295

Answer (score 0):

I have resolved the problem.

This happened because the configuration not adequate.

If you have same situation to me,
please consider to check all below Eclipse debugger's configurations.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]